# How to implement branding in Craft CMS?

Tags: craftcms

I am looking for ideas for what is the best way to implement branding in a Craft CMS website. I essentially would like to display different logo, images, text, URLs on pages based on the brand parameter passed by the URL (e.g https://www.example.com?brand=abc)

Thank you

Comment: You want to add different logo images and URLs based on the URL brand right? 
You can create different entries for the different brands and create fields on those entries like Logo images etc according to your needs and later show them in the front-end.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the value of the `brand` query parameter with
`{% set brand = craft.app.request.getQueryParam('brand') %}`

Then you can just have the bits you want branded change depending upon the value of `brand`.

ie:

```
{% set source = brand == "nike" ? '/logos/swoosh.jpg' : '/logos/default.jpg' %}
<img src="{{source}}">
```

Or maybe...

```
{% set source = brand == "/logos/#{brand}.jpg" ?? '/logos/default.jpg' %}
<img src="{{source}}">
```

[Full docs for the request object](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-web-request.html#method-getqueryparam)